# Twilio - make one call after the other

Tags: javascript, twilio

I would like to make up to 3 calls, on after the other if the call is not answered. I tried doing this in a callback, but ran into issues (well I didn't but my dev team did, so don't have details).

Should it be as simple as iterating on array of numbers, handling exceptions/errors as needed. That way, if one number doesn't pickup, it'll goto the next number?

Note, I am doing this in javascript.

TIA

Comment: In theory it should be possible... But very hard to give you hints without seeing the implementation. Maybe you should sit together with your Dev-Team and talk about the issues and try to solve them as a team.

Comment: Can you, or your dev team, share some of the code you used to try to achieve this. It's hard to help without any details other than there were issues.

Comment: Great points/questions. My dev-team is in india so I won't have an answer until tomorrow AM.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify exactly what you want to achieve, but Twilio offer several of these type of features right out of the box. They are called [Twimlets](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets) and you can integrate them into anything.

These two route incoming callers to the first number within your organisation who picks up:

[Find me](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme) - Calls up to 10 numbers one after the other until one is picked up. You can customise the time each number will ring before calling the next number and set a custom message that will be played to whoever answers the call before they are connected to the incoming caller, they also have the option to decline the call.

[Simulring](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/simulring) - Calls up to 5 numbers simultaneously and connects the incoming caller to whoever answers first. Same options as Find me.

If you are just trying to initiate outbound calls then you use the following and chain several of them together adding the subsequent number to dial as the fail url for the preceding one:

[Forward](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward) - This just forwards to one number and you can specify a follow up action on fail. The main difference is the caller gets connected to whoever answers the phone straightaway, the receiving party doesn't get a recorded message with the option to reject the call.

Each Twimlet page has a form you can fill in which will generate the request for you. There are a few others available too.

Comment: Awesome, Find Me looks like exactly what we need. Not sure how you integrate a Twimlet, but I will FWD to my dev-team. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need any additional functions other than the findme service on your incoming number then you don't need a dev team.
Go to the findme link in my answer above, fill in the form with the numbers you want Twilio to call and it will generate you a URL at the bottom of the page.
Copy the URL and go to incoming number settings in Twilio console, choose configure with "webhooks, TwiML or functions", set a call comes in to "webhook" and paste the URL from the Twimlet page.
Save changes and its all set up.